# How to control transactions on JPA for multiple persist() call with JTA?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, jta

I have multiple tables which are related with each others and I want to rollback all records if occurs an error while persist() at one step of operation.

I have read some questions about JTA is application controled and some examples with UserTranscation.

I am very new at JPA and I just know what I must do.

I need to add record to Table1 with some info and getting this recordId and use it for Table2 with some info and INSERT.If error occurs while adding record to second table I want to rollback whole operation.However, it throws an exception at `em.getTransaction().begin();` and it says `Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.`

Should I use UserTranscation or what should I do for this type multiple persist()?

```
@Dependent
@Transactional
public class UserService extends AbstractService<UserDO> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "UserProjectPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Inject
private UserFooService userFooService;

public UserService() {
    super(UserDO.class);
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public long addUser(UserDO user, String userAnotherInfo) {
    try {

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        UserDO usr = user;
        em.persist(user);
        em.flush();

        long addedUserId = usr.getId();

        UserFooDO userFoo= new UserFooDO();
        userFoo.setContent(userAnotherInfo);
        userFoo.setUserId(addedUserId);
        userFooService.create(userFoo);

        em.getTransaction().commit();

        return addedUserId;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your  _transaction-type_ attribute value in _persistence.xml_ ?

Comment: `<persistence-unit name="UserProjectPU" transaction-type="JTA">` @Mihir

Comment: Which transaction do you want use _JTA_ or _RESOURCE_LOCAL_?

Comment: I wanna use JTA @Mihir

Comment: Follow this link for Better Understanding of _Java Persistence/Transactions_ https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions

Comment: I have read this and its example says use `UserTransaction transaction = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");`. Should I use in that way? @Mihir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110157/discussion-between-mihir-and-cgrgcn).

Comment: You cannot take manual control of `EntityManager`, after you have intended the container to do so.

Comment: Can you give us some more details about your environment?

Comment: @Jaumzera wildfly 8.2.1, resteasy 3.0.2, eclipselink 2.5.2, java7 anything else?

Comment: Once you are using a PersistenceContext you can not handle the transaction boundaries (begin, commit and rollback). JTA transactions are managed by the container, in short: beginning before method and commiting after method.
Also you can try to annotate your class as Stateless (for instance) in order to check whether tx issues are working.

Comment: @Jaumzera thx for advice i will try this.